# How to link tables as one-many in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, progress-4gl, openedge

I am using
OS - Windows 7,
technology - progess 4gl.
I have two tables customer and order. I am displaying customer details along with their orders. Each customer may have more then one order. The report should be as below

CUSTOMER:-
CUMTOMER NAME         ADDRESS
CUSTOMER1             XYZ
ORDER1 OF CUSTOMER1:-
ORDER NO.  ORDER DETAILS
1          ASD
2          ASDFGGH
3          FGHJFG     /* IT SHOULD REPEAT FOR THE PARTICULAR CUTOMER */

CUSTOMER2            ABC
ORDER1 OF CUSTOMER1:-
ORDER NO.  ORDER DETAILS
1          ZXC
2          VNVN
3          JJLK

I Think for this we need one-many relationship between customer and order table. I have only customer and order temp-tables for doing this.Can you please tell me How to repeat the loop inside customer and how to link the tables in one-many relationship. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a stored procedure and then link that SP with your report.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would need anything more complicated than a join.

Something like:

```
select * from customer, order where order.custNum = customer.custNum.
```

Having said that -- you might find this Progress Knowledgebase article relevant. Some versions of Crystal apparently produce SQL that might need to be adjusted:

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/18979

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are just having an issue with how it is shown, I would join the table like Tom suggested `order.custNum = customer.custNum`
but in the Design section I would do the following:

```
GH1a  Customer Name
GH1b  Customer Information
GH2   Order Number
Det   Order Information
```

you could also place all of the Customer Information (name, addr, etc) into a formula so that if the customer doesn't have all the data filled in it won't be shown, and won't show a blank line.